# rspec testing for order of json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

So my code is returning json like this:

```
    "offenses": [
    {
    "name": "Speeding",
    "penalties": [
    {
    "name": "Ticket",
    "severity": "Medium"
    }

}
]
```

I have the following fatcory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person_offense_penalty do
    person_offense
    name 'Ticket'
    severity 'Medium'
  end
end



FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person_offense do
    name 'Speeding'
    person
  end
end
```

Here my testing for the response and it works fine

```
  person_offenses = person.person_offenses
  expect(response_body['offenses'].size).to eq(person_offenses.size)



   person_offenses.each_with_index do |offense, offense_index|
        expect(response_body['offenses'][offense_index]['name']).to eq(offense.name)
        offense.person_offense_penaltys.each_with_index do |penalty, penalty_index|
          expect(response_body['offenses'][offense_index]['penaltys'][penalty_index]['name']).to eq(penalty.name)
          expect(response_body['offenses'][offense_index]['penaltys'][penalty_index]['severity']).to eq(penalty.severity)
        end
      end
```

I need to write another test that makes sure the offense names are sorted in ascending order.
Can someone help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get your JSON into a valid string:

```
[1] pry(main)> x = "{\"offenses\": [{ \"name\": \"Speeding\", \"penalties\": [ { \"name\": \"Ticket\", \"severity\": \"Medium\" } ] }] }"
```

Now we can parse it [`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html#method-c-decode)

```
[2] pry(main)> offenses = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(x)["offenses"]
=> [{"name"=>"Speeding", "penalties"=>[{"name"=>"Ticket", "severity"=>"Medium"}]}]
```

You can get a list of the offense names with [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
[3] pry(main)> names = offenses.map { |o| o["name"] }
=> ["Speeding"]
```

Now you can simply [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) the names and compare

```
expect(names).to eq(names.sort)
```

This will pass if the original JSON has each `"offense"` in place ordered by it's `"name"` property.